# Are our traffic statistics broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

I have been keeping track of site statistics since October 2016 and I recently noticed a sharp drop in the number of visitors per day (as reported on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning)):

- 10.04: 140 (it had been this low for several days)
- 11.04: 134
- 12.04: ? (forgot to record the data)
- 13.04: 94
- 14.04: 42
- 15.04: 3 so far

**Is this a bug, or are we really losing traffic that badly?**

Note: Rand al'Thor noticed a [similar issue on Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1019/2191).

Comment: I've been doing a little "proselytizing" at my university. Hopefully I'm not scaring people away!

Comment: Thank you, apostle Hatchet ;-) It's just the statistics that are (still) broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be so.

These two Meta.SE questions seem to be relevant:

- [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/187133)
- [Traffic isn't updated correctly on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309064/187133)

**Update 03.07.2018**: it seems that the visits/day issue was fixed today or yesterday, at least on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning), where it says that we currently have 151 visits per day. (This number is too low for graduated sites but plausible for our site.)